# Run scp as ubuntu@ copying to Ubuntu system with correct permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp

I ssh into a ubuntu box with username "ubuntu" and I can become root without entering a password via "sudo su". How can I scp files onto this box using the ubuntu@ username? It does not allow me to do so using root@. The error is:

```
scp: /etc/...: Permission denied
```

I can do this same task in rsync by using --rsync-path="sudo rsync" for example.

Comment: You might want to post this on superuser.com instead - that's just like Stack Overflow but precisely for answering this sort of question - you'll get a better response there than here.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, use rsync with the sudo trick. scp won't preserve permissions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can either SCP them as the user and then log in and copy them as root.  Since SCP can't `su`, there's not a good way to do it unless you change `root`'s password.

(I thought you would have to add `PermitRootLogin yes` to /etc/sshd/sshd.cofig, but it [seems Ubuntu uses the random-root-password method](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7913576) instead of locking out root)